# Exclamation mark after autocommands

Tags: vimrc, autocmd, functions

I'm trying to understand what does exclamation mark after autocommands mean.

Sometimes it is possible to see something like this:

```
function! LangSpecificOptions()
  if (&filetype == 'markdown' || &filetype == 'html')
    set wrap
  else
    set nowrap        
  endif
endfunction
autocmd! BufReadPost,BufNewFile * call LangSpecificOptions()
```

I already found what "!" means when placed after the function:

> **Bao Niu:** I am learning Vimscript and I wonder if there is any difference between writing "function!" vs. "function"? What is that exclamation point for here?
>
> **Tim Chase:** As detailed at `:help E123`, if a function already exists with the same name as you want to 
>   create, the "!" will tell it to overwrite the previously-existing 
>   function.  Thus, you might have
>
> ```
> function Hello() 
>   echo 'Hello' 
> endfunction
> ```
>
> and then want to change it, so you'd use
>
> ```
> function! Hello() 
>   echoerr 'Hello' 
> endfunction
> ```
>
> to overwrite it.  Because of the behavior, I just use the "!" *every* 
>   time that I define a function.  That way, I don't have to think about 
>   whether it already exists or not.
>
> Source: http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/why-quot-function-quot-instead-of-just-quot-function-quot-td5723708.html

However, I haven't found similar explanation for autocommands.

## Edit:

As it correctly stated in comments by @mass, "!" after autocommands mean that this autocommand should be removed. Well, then another question:

What's the purpose of removing autocommands?

Comment: it is documented at `:help autocmd-remove`, has nothing to do with `function!`

Comment: Hmm, thanks. Trying to understand what I read just now in help section.

Comment: Deleting autocommands is used in augroups. `:help :augroup`

Comment: `What's the purpose of removing autocommands?`: It clears the autocommand group, making sure that no old leftover command is there and you start from a fresh clean state. Note: that recently the behaviour of `func!` also changed recently. Since 8.1.573, you can skip the `!` if simply trying to redefine the same function if it is in the same script.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt and Ralf - thanks. Well, I read something about autocommand groups (never used them before). And it seems the code where I see this exclamation mark doesn't really need it. It was here: http://shallowsky.com/blog/linux/editors/vim-settings-by-file.html

Comment: @johnc.j. I assume it's used because of functionality of resourcing vim configuration. Imagine following:
-> you copy/paste following lines in your config
-> open vim to check functionality
-> change it in place and resource vim config (without exiting)

as a result, without ! your active configuration will contain two autocommands for same event+pattern (BufReadPost,BufNewFile *)